# Django: Method Not Allowed (POST):

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an event in FullCalendar by passing a timestamp into the url of a Django CreateView. However, after pressing submit on my form I keep getting a blank page and the error:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /fullcalendar/ambroses-calendar/
```

html:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    if($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').type != 'month') {
        $("#occDiv").load("{% url 'edit_occurrence_short' 1234567898765 %}".replace(1234567898765, (new Date(date)).getTime())).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 800
    });
    $("#occDiv").dialog('open');
}
```

urls.py

```
   url(r'^occurrence/add/(?P<date>\d+)/$',
        ShortCreateOccurrenceView.as_view(),
        name='edit_occurrence_short')
```

Views.py:

```
class ShortOccurrenceMixin(CalendarViewPermissionMixin, TemplateResponseMixin):
    model = Occurrence
    pk_url_kwarg = 'occurrence_id'
    form_class = ShortOccurrenceForm

class ShortCreateOccurrenceView(ShortOccurrenceMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'schedule/edit_occurrence_short.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        occurrence = form.save(commit=False)
        start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.kwargs.get('date', None)/1000.0)
        end = start + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        occurrence.start = start
        occurrence.end = end
        occurrence.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
```

Models.py:

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("event"))
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("description"), blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(_("start"), db_index=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(_("end"), db_index=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(_("cancelled"), default=False)
    original_start = models.DateTimeField(_("original start"), auto_now=True)
    original_end = models.DateTimeField(_("original end"), auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_("created on"),   auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(_("updated on"), auto_now=True)
```

Forms.py:

```
class ShortOccurrenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Occurrence
        fields = ('title', 'event')
```

Comment: Is it possible that you root it to another view, the view in your error does *not* match the URL pattern you share here.

Comment: Oh interesting. Yes, I am routing the form url through a dialog box. It must think that the POST url is from the main page, not the dialog box

Comment: Look at your `<form>` tag in your browser developer tools, what's the `action` attribute set to? If you don't set it explicitly the form is always submitted to the current URL of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments under the question led me to the right answer. Thank you very much @Willhen Van Onsem and @dirkgroten!

I was able to change the origin of the form POST by setting the action on the form in the html

```
...
<form action="{% url 'edit_occurrence_short' date %}" method="post" >
...
```